# Discord.py - Return an embed from a function

Tags: discord.py

When I return an embed from my function it return `<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x00000250B37841F0>` when I try to send it from an another function (with `await ctx.send(console_create()`).
Here's my code:

````
def console_create():
    embed=discord.Embed(title="```CONSOLE\n```", color=0xfd3030)
    embed.add_field(name="test", value="...")
    embed.set_footer(text="Ici s'affiche les messages d'erreurs...")
    return embed
````

I think I just forgot to add something obvious in the return's line......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
await ctx.send(embed=console_create())
```

Tada. You just needed to specify where to pass the embed

Answer (score 0):

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
#if the message is from the bot itself ignore it
if message.author == bot.user:
return
#else if the message is Hello send Hello World as reply
if message.content == 's-help':
#making a embed object
embed = discord.Embed(
title='Hello',
description="This is a embed",
colour=discord.Colour(0x1253f3),
)
#making a dictionary of the embed
embed_to_dic=embed.to_dict()

```
    # sending the embed
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    #sending the dictionary created as message
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).